# My asp.net MVC Program looks not right when i open it on debug

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, debugging

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cPRh5JsWG3wBjTyZhyYIppfZBA0nrFpB?usp=sharing

In the above pictures, in the right side is my project when i open it with Ctrl+F5 and on the left side is my project when i open it on debug, using F5, in two different pages.

I noticed a small diffrence in the html code when i inspected it, as you can see in the second picture i uploaded(In the left side there are "::before" and "::after" missing).
other then that there is no diffrence i can point on in the html.

Please help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer.

Everything worked just fine after i have upgraded to bootstrap 4. 
Note that when moving from Bootstrap 3 to 4, the default layout that you get with the asp.net application will no longer behave properly, Bootstrap 3 and 4 are quite different and things that worked in the 3th version may not work in the 4th.